# Oracle trigger after insert on

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I am trying to create a trigger on `ComputerTable` to update the insert operation in `TableWithTrigger`

I have SemesterID in SemesterDim table and TimeID in TimePeriodDim table. I declare the two variables at the beginning to call the other two attributes and update the TempSemesterID and TempTimeID with a value by comparing conditions.

Here is my code:

```
create or replace trigger UpdateTrigger
  after insert on ComputerTable
  referencing new as new old as old
  for each row
  declare
  TempSemesterID     SemesterDim.SemesterID%type;
  TempTimeID         TimePeriodDim.TimeID%type;
  
begin
  if (to_char(LoginDate, 'MM/DD') >= '01/01')
    and (to_char(LoginDate, 'MM/DD') <= '07/15') then
    TempSemesterID := 'S1';
  else
    TempSemesterID := 'S2';
  end if;

  if (to_char(LoginTime, 'HH24:MI') >= '06:00')
    and (to_char(LoginTime, 'HH24:MI') < '12:00') then
    TempTimeID := '1';
  elsif (to_char(LoginTime, 'HH24:MI') >= '12:00')
    and (to_char(LoginTime, 'HH24:MI') < '18:00') then
    TempTimeID := '2';
  else
    TempTimeID := '3';
  end if;
  
  insert into TableWithTrigger
  values (:new.LoginTime, :new.LoginDate,
  :new.DegreeCode, :new.StudentNo, TempSemesterID, TempTimeID);
  
end UpdateTrigger;
/
```

I got errors like :

> Error(70,3): PL/SQL: Statement ignored;
> Error(70,15): PLS-00201: identifier 'LOGINDATE' must be declared;
> Error(77,3): PL/SQL: Statement ignored;
> Error(77,15): PLS-00201: identifier 'LOGINTIME' must be declared;

I have no ideas on how to fix them, hope someone can help me with it.

Answer (score -1):

The `:new` notation applies to columns on the owning table. It looks like you are trying to populate local variables. So, just remove the namespace from the assignments. Note that you need to include `:new.` when you are referencing a column. Your IF statements reference table columns, so you need to add `:new.` to those references, like this:

```
  if (to_char(:new.LoginDate, 'MM/DD') >= '01/01')
    and (to_char(:new.LoginDate, 'MM/DD') <= '07/15') then
    TempSemesterID := 'S1';
  else
    TempSemesterID := 'S2';
  end if;
```

> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "UpdateTrigger" when expecting one of the following: if

You got that error because you used ELSE IF in the switch statement, In PL/SQL the correct syntax is ELSIF. As you have it, you have started a nested IF block, and the compiler is expecting `end UpdateTrigger;` to be the matching `end if` statement.

Here is a version of your code which compiles:

```
create or replace trigger UpdateTrigger
  after insert on ComputerTable
  for each row
  declare
  TempSemesterID     SemesterDim.SemesterID%type;
  TempTimeID         TimePeriodDim.TimeID%type;
  
begin
  
  if (to_char(:new.LoginDate, 'MM/DD') >= '01/01')
    and (to_char(:new.LoginDate, 'MM/DD') <= '07/15') then
    TempSemesterID := 'S1';
  else
    TempSemesterID := 'S2';
  end if;

  if (to_char(:new.LoginTime, 'HH24:MI') >= '06:00')
    and (to_char(:new.LoginTime, 'HH24:MI') < '12:00') then
    TempTimeID := '1';
  elsif (to_char(:new.LoginTime, 'HH24:MI') >= '12:00')
    and (to_char(:new.LoginTime, 'HH24:MI') < '18:00') then
    TempTimeID := '2';
  else
    TempTimeID := '3';
  end if;
  
  insert into TableWithTrigger
  values (:new.LoginTime, :new.LoginDate,
  :new.DegreeCode, :new.StudentNo, TempSemesterID, TempTimeID);
  
end UpdateTrigger;
/
```

Here is a demo on [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a56ee90634d8b33330559c3667f74131)

Comment: Hi, I deleted all   :new.  before the TempSemesterID and TempTimeID; one error pops up: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "TableWithTrigger" when expecting one of the following:
         if. Please help me with it, I think only few steps left to make it.

Comment: sorry, the error is(92,5): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "UpdateTrigger" when expecting one of the following:     if

Comment: Updated the codes, please have a check in the post.

Comment: I had to create sample tables so I could compile your trigger code and debug it fully. I would have answered your question faster if you had supplied the DDL to create the tables instead of leaving it to me to re-create your work. Please bear this in mind the next time you ask a question which is a compilation error. Also, if you have found my answer helpful please consider upvoting and or accepting it. Accepted answers improve the value of this site for other Seekers.

Answer (score -1):

When you refer to column names in your table that the trigger is on, you need to use either `:old.` or `:new.` prefixes so the code will know whether you are referencing the old value or the new value.

Comment: Hi Wweicker, I did what you said, here are the new codes with errors, please help me with it. Thanks

Comment: @YYYYY is `LoginDate` a column in table `UpdateTrigger`? Try adding `:new.` in front of any column references.

Comment: The default namespaces are OLD and NEW. So it is not necessary to include the REFERENCING clause in the trigger definition. We only need to do that if, for some unknown reason, we want to use something other than OLD and NEW (which I would regard as very bad practice).

Comment: @wweiker, by adding :new.. It works. Thank you so much for you help.

Comment: @APC good to know, but strange that in adding that the error message changed... maybe they are running an old Oracle version, or we weren't provided with full/accurate information.

Comment: There were several syntax errors in the trigger. Fixing one lot of errors threw up the next one. Please read my answer to understand what's going on.

Comment: @YYYYY you're welcome. On StackOverflow, rather than saying "thanks" in the comments it is customary and more valuable to others to up-vote an answer that helped you and accept the answer that was the most valuable to answering the question so that when others find this question later they can quickly and easily zero in on any useful information that might help them.